# Applescript "Google Chrome got an error: Can’t make |tabs| of window id 1 into type specifier."

Tags: applescript

New to Applescript.

Trying to make a script that will cycle through my tabs, printing each tab to PDF.

Starting from here...

[Example of working Google Chrome Applescript](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/345138/applescript-save-all-open-tabs-in-chrome-to-pdf)

...but trying to generalize to work with all of Google Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. To start this modification, I began by looking [here](https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?p=1729425) and [here](https://www.alfredforum.com/topic/2013-how-to-get-frontmost-tab%E2%80%99s-url-and-title-of-various-browsers/).

I'm getting tripped up right off the bat, noticing that a small change can make a big difference ...

NO ERROR:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    set myWindow to front window
    set myTabs to tabs in myWindow
    --Do more stuff here...
end tell
```

ERROR:

```
set webBrowser to "Google Chrome"
tell application webBrowser
    set myWindow to front window
    set myTabs to tabs in myWindow
    --Do more stuff here...
end tell
```

The error I'm getting is:

"Google Chrome got an error: Can’t make |tabs| of window id 1 into type specifier." The "offending object" in this error is "tabs of window id 1", and it's telling me that the expected type is "reference".

Any ideas how to proceed? Thanks for any help.

Justin

EDIT:

```
set webBrowser to "Firefox" -- or Safari
set pdfMenuItemTitle to "Save as PDF…" -- the title of the menu item you want
set myDelay to 0.2

tell application webBrowser to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell process webBrowser
        -- open the print dialog
        click menu item "Print…" of menu 1 of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1
        delay myDelay

        --Do more stuff here...

    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: A variable can't be used for the target of a tell statement - the scripting terminology for any given application needs to be declared at _compile_ time.

Comment: @red_menace ... Thanks for the reply :). Quick question, though ... See my edit ... why does the EDIT section code work?

Comment: It works because you aren't using an application's scripting terminology, you are scripting the user interface via System Events (which is being declared at compile time).

Answer (score 0):

No, the point is not at all that you cannot use a variable in the **tell** block of the application. It can be done, only it is not efficient from a programming point of view. Because then you need to tell AppleScript where to get from the **terms** like **tabs** used in the tell block.

Purely for demonstration purposes:

```
set webBrowser to (choose from list {"Google Chrome", "Safari", "FireFox"})
if webBrowser is false then return
set webBrowser to item 1 of webBrowser

tell application webBrowser
    if webBrowser is "Google Chrome" then
        using terms from application "Google Chrome"
            set myTabs to tabs in front window
        end using terms from
    else if webBrowser is "Safari" then
        using terms from application "Safari"
            set myTabs to tabs in front window
        end using terms from
    else -- it is Firefox. It has only windows, not the tabs.
        set myTabs to front window
    end if
end tell
```

In practice, it is better not to be perverted, but to do it like this:

```
set webBrowser to (choose from list {"Google Chrome", "Safari", "FireFox"})
if webBrowser is false then return
set webBrowser to item 1 of webBrowser

if webBrowser is "Google Chrome" then
    tell application "Google Chrome" to set myTabs to tabs in front window
else if webBrowser is "Safari" then
    tell application "Safari" to set myTabs to tabs in front window
else -- it is Firefox. It has only windows, not the tabs.
    tell application "Firefox" to set myTabs to front window
end if
```